# Fluctuating ping to a certain ISP backbone

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

There's a central server that located 300 miles away from my country. but when i test the ping to that server or their ISP backbone, i get inconsistent or a fluctuated pings from there. i live in Saudi Arabia, and the server is located in Qatar (300miles away).

So here's a screenshot showing a traceroute from my computer to that server:

[image]

However, This problem doesn't happen to any other servers from various locations.

So is this considered to be normal? if no. how can it be fixed?

UPDATE: Wait, i found out something! when i try pinging my friend who lives there and hires the same ISP, i get a stable ping times of 25-27 ms with no problems! and when i try to traceroute to his dynamic IP, i get almost the same hops from there, but it still shows inconsistent ping to these static ip servers until it reaches his home which surprisingly shows a constant and stable ping times to him. Could it be that his ISP configured their dynamic IPs to choose a special route to my ISP which was waaay better than what they chose for their static ip servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, latency will vary on public internet circuits. The only way to avoid this is to either ensure you control the entire path from client to server or to find an ISP that will give you guarantees on latency to certain locations.

Either will be expensive.

Comment: Oh i see. Well is it possible that this potential issue is called Load-balancing? where packets are switched over time to an alternative routers?

Comment: No, it's more likely that the increased latency is due to link congestion along the path.

Comment: Ok. So it's affecting everything like Real-Time Applications and Video Games, no matter what!? D:

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Are you sure? I asked someone i know who knowledgeable about it, and he told me it could be that the ICMP packets are being treated as low-priority, and nothing looks out of ordinary and it's completely normal. (Sorry just curious)

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the ISP is treating ICMP any differently than any other IP traffic.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much but, this is a traceroute from My ISP to the same ISP backbone located in another city from my country here (500miles aprox) : http://i.stack.imgur.com/BbQjm.png                                                                                                          is this also the same?

Comment: Please ask another question if you please instead of carrying on in comments.

Comment: Ok. Here: http://serverfault.com/questions/716561/inconsistent-ping-to-my-isp-backbone