# Inconsistent ping to my ISP backbone

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

this is a traceroute from My ISP to the same ISP backbone located in another city from my country here (500miles aprox) : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbQjm.png
Does this idicate a traceroute problem? And will this affect some real-time applications and video games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing a trace route indicates is how long an ICMP packet takes to get to and from each route hop between your source and destination IPs. Period.

If you want to test how a certain application will perform, you need to test and profile **that application**.